# Linux (Ubuntu vs CentOS) LDAP Client for 389-ds - password policy

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, fedora

389-ds on Ubuntu 12.04 server up and running. Enabled `Fine-grained password policies` and `User must change password after reset` for the whole tree. Created test user afterwards.

Login from CentOS client: user gets prompted to change its password: `You are required to change your password immediately.`

Login from Ubuntu client: user logs in, **no prompt**.

Copied CentOS client configuration files to Ubuntu client, precisely /etc/pam_ldap.conf (on Ubuntu this is /etc/ldap.conf), /etc/nslcd.conf, /etc/openldap/ldap.conf (on Ubuntu /etc/ldap/ldap.conf) - no dice.

Both clients authenticate successfully, both can change user passwords.

All logins are terminal logins, no GUI involved.

PAM on both clients:

1. Ubuntu:

   - /etc/pam.d/common-account

     > account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]
     >   pam_unix.so   account [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so 
     >   account requisite                       pam_deny.so account required
     >   pam_permit.so
   - /etc/pam.d/common-auth

     > auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure auth
     >   [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so use_first_pass auth
     >   requisite                       pam_deny.so auth    required
     >   pam_permit.so auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
   - /etc/pam.d/common-password

     > password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure
     >   sha512 password        [success=1 user_unknown=ignore default=die]
     >   pam_ldap.so try_first_pass password        requisite
     >   pam_deny.so password        required
     >   pam_permit.so password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
2. CentOS

   - /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac

     > #%PAM-1.0 auth        required      pam_env.so auth        sufficient
     >   pam_fprintd.so auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok
     >   try_first_pass auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500
     >   quiet auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass auth
     >   required      pam_deny.so
     >
     > account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow account
     >   sufficient    pam_localuser.so account     sufficient
     >   pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet account     [default=bad success=ok
     >   user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so account     required
     >   pam_permit.so
     >
     > password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
     >   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok
     >   try_first_pass use_authtok password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so
     >   use_authtok password    required      pam_deny.so
     >
     > session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke session     required
     >   pam_limits.so session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so session
     >   [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet
     >   use_uid session     required      pam_unix.so session     optional
     >   pam_ldap.so
   - /etc/pam.d/passwd-auth-ac

     > #%PAM-1.0 auth        required      pam_env.so auth        sufficient
     >   pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass auth        requisite
     >   pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet auth        sufficient
     >   pam_ldap.so use_first_pass auth        required      pam_deny.so
     >
     > account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow account
     >   sufficient    pam_localuser.so account     sufficient
     >   pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet account     [default=bad success=ok
     >   user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so account     required
     >   pam_permit.so
     >
     > password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
     >   password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok
     >   try_first_pass use_authtok password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so
     >   use_authtok password    required      pam_deny.so
     >
     > session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke session     required
     >   pam_limits.so session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so session
     >   [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet
     >   use_uid session     required      pam_unix.so session     optional
     >   pam_ldap.so

One difference is that on Ubuntu I do not have cracklib installed. I plan to do so later, now I am just testing.

I wonder if Ubuntu LDAP client joins Windows AD, how does it receive notifications for password expiration from it. It should be something similar but I can't figure it out.

How to make the Ubuntu client to honour/obey the password policies? Why I don't see the `You are required to change your password immediately.` prompt when login, given that the same config works with CentOS?

Thank you!

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with 389-ds on Ubuntu for a work project and came across the exact same issue.

I'm not sure about copying the config over from CentOS - I didn't have a box handy.

But when I looked and read up on PAM, it turned out to all be in the file ***/etc/pam.d/common-account***.

pam_unix.so was above pam_ldap.so, and it also had [success=2 default=ignore], which means if it succeeds skip the next two rules, and for anything else, ignore the line.

Now since LDAP accounts are valid UNIX accounts since we added ldap to ***/etc/nsswitch.conf***, this rule will return success and the pam_ldap.so module will never get run.

To get around this, my ***/etc/pam.d/common-account*** now looks like this:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=1 default=bad]  pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup auth-access quiet
account [success=reset default=bad]  pam_succeed_if.so uid <= 500 quiet
account [success=2 user_unknown=ignore default=ok]      pam_ldap.so
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

As you can see, I've also added some rules in there to only allow users in either the LDAP group "auth-access", or system users with a UID below 500 to be seen as valid accounts.

And to explain a little:

We hit the first rule

```
account [success=1 default=bad]  pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup auth-access quiet
```

Which succeeds if the user is in that group and if so, we skip the next line as we know that'll fail (they're a valid LDAP user, so they won't have a system UID below 500) - if it doesn't succeed, return a fail (bad).

Then the next rule if it wasn't skipped

```
account [success=reset default=bad]  pam_succeed_if.so uid <= 500 quiet
```

So if this on succeeds (because the UID is below 500), reset the fail value set by the module above, because they won't be part of that LDAP group.

And the important part

```
account [success=2 user_unknown=ignore default=ok]      pam_ldap.so
```

Check the LDAP server for the account status - if it succeeds, we know an LDAP user is a valid UNIX user, so go ahead and skip the next two lines (to take us to pam_permit.so and let the user login). If the user is unknown to the LDAP server, ignore this line and move to the next one - and for all other statuses, "ok" means it's ok to pass those return codes as-is, which will pass things like password expired, etc.

And then:

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so
```

We weren't a valid LDAP user if we hit this rule, so check if we're a valid system user - if succeed, skip next 1 line (takes us to pam_permit.so). Otherwise, ignore, which will take us to pam_deny.so.

Hope that helps explain a little more - the document that helped me if I wasn't very easy to understand was: http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SEC_pam/pam-4.html

Regards,
iamacarpet